# Native message exe not getting invoked since Chrome update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am using Native messaging to communicate from my chrome extension and system.

Since I am also developing the extension, so I install the extension by loading the unpacked extension in the Chrome. I had to frequently delete the extension as well while developing.

It was working fine but few days back when Chrome got updated, the native exe is not getting invoked. **Current Chrome version is 37.0.2062.120 m 32-bit.**

Here is what the configuration of my extension.
I am using chrome.runtime.connectNative("com.foo") in background.js

In the registry the entry is

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.foo]
@="C:\\Program Files\\ChromeNative\\nativeMessage.json"
```

nativeMessage.json looks like this

```
{  
    "name": "com.foo",  
    "description": "Chrome Native Messaging API Example Host",  
    "path": "native.exe",  
    "type": "stdio",  
    "allowed_origins": [  
      "chrome-extension://<extension id>/"  
    ]  
}
```

native.exe is present in the same directory where nativeMessage.json is present.

Please help me in invoking the native exe.

Comment: I don't think your registry key is properly set up. Can you export it and show the resulting `reg` file?

Comment: Here is the result of the .ref file that I exported:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.foo]
@="C:\\Program Files\\ChromeNative\\nativeMessage.json"

Comment: Edit the question to include it.

Comment: I'm building a Chrome extension for the first time and also can't get native messaging hosts to launch (unfortunately I don't have a copy of Chrome 36 to test against). Looks like it might be broke on Linux too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595313/chrome-native-messaging-host-stopped-working-in-chrome-37-linux

Comment: Probably.. But no one seems to have any interest or information regarding this issue.

Comment: @Akhil The question is lacks too many details (in particular error messages). Can you look at the new native messaging documentation (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), double-check all debugging tips and report back (with error messages and code) if you are still having trouble with getting your extension to work?